# Quantum algorithms and binomial distributions and probabilities

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, experimental-realization

Qubits in a quantum computer are mostly spins of quantum particles.But since spin can take up to 2 values does this mean quantum algorithms are applied mathematics which make use of binomial distributions and probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a number $n$ of ***unentangled*** qubits and measure these qubits in the computational basis, then indeed the measurement statistics and the counts of the number of times you measure a spin-up qubit (or a $|0\rangle$ qubit) will be based on the binomial distribution, much as flipping fair a coin $n$ and recording the number of times the coin lands heads will also be distributed according to the binomial distribution.

But, one feature of qubits that makes quantum computing more interesting than all that is that the $n$ qubits can be ***entangled*** with one another, and certain measurement statistics can deviate, sometimes significantly, such that you are much less likely to have the number of or arrangement of spin-up qubits behave according to the binomial distribution.  Search, for example, for the generalized GHZ state, or the generalized W state.

Oftentimes, however, the deviations afforded by entanglement are more subtle than just counting the number of times a qubit is measured in the $|0\rangle$ basis to see if the count obeys the binomial distribution. For example, consider certain quantum supremacy experiments including the landmark Google experiment from 2019.  Therein it was known that the noisy qubits and noisy gates behaved such that often there would be loss of entanglement and the measured output string would be uniformly distributed over all $2^{53}$ such strings, and then necessarily the count of qubits measured in $|0\rangle$ obeys the binomial distribution.  But even in the rarer instances when the circuit was executed perfectly, the number of $|0\rangle$'s measured could (would?) also obey the binomial distribution, although it was the statistics of ***each 53-qubit string***  that deviated from the uniform distribution.